# Transfer audio file to alexa as a query

Tags: testing, alexa-skills-kit, end-to-end

For an automated end-to-end test environment I am supposed to use alexa. Instead of playing an speech audiofile and make alexa listening to the speech, I want to transfer the audiofile directly to alexa (via its API?) in order to make it easily repeatable. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Do you need to be able to transfer to an actual device, or is transferring to the cloud service acceptable?

Comment: via cloud is acceptable. i just need to see if alexa does understand the query, find the right skill and does give it back.